# Problems while comparing years and sizes of file in batch

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I've a doubt for doing a comparison (if statement's) inside a for loop:
I've a lot of files inside a folder, and I want to make two comparisons:

1. If the file was created at the current year (!dateFile:~6,4! equ %date:~6,4%)
2. If the size of the file is 0 bytes (%%~Za equ 0)

When I find a file that complies these conditions, I want to show "ok".

I've the next line of code, but it doesn't work:

```
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d "FOLDER\"') do set dateFile=%%~ta if ((!dateFile:~6,4! equ %date:~6,4%) & (%%~Za equ 0)) echo "ok"
```

Some help? Thanks :)

Comment: `... do set "dateFile=%%~ta" & if ...` - (assuming you have delayed expansion enabled.)

Comment: @Stephan yes, I have "setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion" at the beginning of my code, and with that change continues failing :(

Comment: `if (a equ a) & (b equ b) ...` doesn't work. You want `if a equ a if b equ b ...` instead.

Comment: Something like that? `for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d "FOLDER\"') do set dateFile=%%~ta & if !dateFile:~6,4! equ %date:~6,4% & if %%~Za equ 0 echo "ok"`

Comment: No. Same issues as before. Read my two previous comments again.

Comment: So, same code but removing '&' between if statement's?

Comment: Yes. `&` in batch cascades commands.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that the first if-statement doesn't have a correct syntaxis, because I continue with errors.

Comment: see my first comment again.

Comment: Sorry, modified: `for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d "FOLDER\"') do set "dateFile=%%~ta" & if %%~Za equ 0 if !dateFile:~6,4! equ %date:~6,4% echo "ok"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

First: your `set` command adds more to the variable than you want.
Use the preferred syntax `set "var=value"` to avoid that.

Second: to concatenate commands, use `&` (missing in your code between `set` and `if`)

Third: your `if` syntax is off. `if (a equ a) & (b equ b) ...` doesn't work.
You want `if a equ a if b equ b ...` instead.

Fourth: another (unexpected) issue: due to when delayed expansion happens, the comma(s) in `!var:6,4!` aren't safe and kill the `if` syntax. Quote both sides of the comparison to avoid that (forcing a string comparison, but commas and other "poison characters" are safe within quotes).

All in all, the following should work for you:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d ') do set "dateFile=%%~ta" & if "!dateFile:~6,4!" equ "!date:~6,4!" if %%~Za equ 0 echo "ok"
```

Although I'm not a fan of "one-line" solutions - they tend to be hard to read and even harder to maintain, so I suggest using:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d ') do (
  set "dateFile=%%~ta"
  if "!dateFile:~6,4!" equ "!date:~6,4!" if %%~Za equ 0 echo "ok"
)
```

Comment: Ooohh thanks Stephan, I didn't know about using "" in `!var:~6,4!`.

Comment: Don't mind. I fell into the same trap (therefore `(unexpected) issue`) `:)`